# null reference when declaring a class as a window resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mainwindow

I have problems with accessibility to a class, from the MainWindow code behind.

I have written this class:

```
namespace WpfApp1.Management
{
    public class BookManagement : INotifyPropertyChanged
    { ...
```

which is referenced in MainWindow:

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    x:Name="mainWindow"
    ...
    xmlns:mangmt="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.Management"
```

by:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <mangmt:BookManagement x:Key="bookManagement" />
</Window.Resources>
```

the fact is that I need to access to bookManagement from MainWindow.cs, and I tried this:

```
BookManagement bm= Application.Current.Resources["bookManagement"] as BookManagement;
bm.SelectedTab = "summary";
```

but I get a null reference exception at runtime.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is part of your `MainWindow`'s resources, not part of the application:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <mangmt:BookManagement x:Key="bookManagement" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Use this to retrieve it instead:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Resources["bookManagement"]
```